# No output in tic-tac-toe?

Tags: java, tic-tac-toe

Currently doing a school project in java of tic-tac-toe, feel the code is inherently right but when i try to output it won't do the print function and keeps indicating a winner, also the print function itself doesn't output the BLANK, CROSS OR NOUGHT when it has been assigned to those. Any help would be hugely appreciated

```
    public static void printBoard(char[][] board)
    {
        for(int i=0;i<NUMBER_OF_ROWS;i++)
        {
            System.out.println();

            for(int j=0;j<NUMBER_OF_COLUMNS;j++)
            {
                if(j==0)
                {
                    System.out.print("| ");
                }
                System.out.print(board[i][j] + " | ");
            }
        }
    }
public static boolean isBoardFull(char[][] board)
    {
        for(int i=0;i>NUMBER_OF_ROWS;i++)
        {
            for(int j=0;j>NUMBER_OF_COLUMNS;j++)
            {
                if(board[i][j]==BLANK)
                {
                    return false;
                }
            }
            }
        return true;
    }
public static char winner( char[][] board)
    {
        char winner = BLANK;
        for( int row = 0; row < board.length; row++)
        {
            if( board[row][0] == board[row][1] && board[row][1] == board[row][2])
            {
                winner = board[row][0];
            }
        }

        for( int column = 0; column < board.length; column++)
        {
            if(board[0][column] == board[1][column] && board[1][column] == board[2][column])
            {
                winner = board[0][column];
            }
        }

        if( board[0][0] == board[1][1] && board[1][1] == board[2][2])
        {
            winner = board[0][0];
        }

        if( board[0][2] == board[1][1] && board[1][1] == board[2][0])
        {
            winner = board[0][2];
        }
        return winner;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        boolean finished = false;
        char[][] board = new char[NUMBER_OF_ROWS][NUMBER_OF_COLUMNS];
        clearBoard(board);
        int playerNumber = 1;
        System.out.println("Player 1:Noughts\nPlayer 2: Crosses");

        while(!finished)
        {
        if(isBoardFull(board))
        {
            finished = true;
            if(winner(board)==BLANK)
            {
                System.out.print("The match is a draw ");
            }
            else
            {
                System.out.print("The winner is" + (winner(board)==CROSS?" Player 1":" Player 2"));
            }
        }

        System.out.println("Enter place on board you wish to make a move for " 
                + (playerNumber%2!=0?"Player 1":"Player 2") + "(row,column): ");
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        input.useDelimiter(",");
        int row = input.nextInt() - 1;
        int column = input.nextInt() - 1;       
        if(!canMakeMove(board,row,column))
        {
            System.out.print("Cannot make move, please enter "
                    + "coordinates within range and not previously entered");
        }
        else
        {
            makeMove(board, row, column, playerNumber);
            printBoard(board);
            playerNumber++;
            if(winner(board) != BLANK)
            {
                System.out.println("The winner is" + (winner(board)==CROSS?" Player 1":" Player 2"));
                finished = true;
            }
        }


        }
    }
```

Comment: This looks wrong: `for(int i=0;i>NUMBER_OF_ROWS;i++)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your isBoardFull method `i>NUMBER_OF_ROWS` and `j>NUMBER_OF_COLUMNS` conditions are wrong,it should be other way.
Because of this it will always return `true` ie board is full